# Elasticsearch: 'x_content_parse_exception', [bool] failed to parse field [must]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting the error:

> BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:34] [bool] failed to parse field [must]')

following is my source code:

```
query ={
  
   "size":50,
   "_source": "Title", 
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "knn":{
                  "vectors":{
                     "vector":token_vector,
                     "k":20
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}

res = es.search(index='posting', body=query)
```

I am using the latest version of elasticsearch (8.5.2)

I also searched for similar questions raised before but unfortunately, I could not get any answers satisfying my question.

Answer (score 0):

Knn is parameter search query. Try like this

```
{
   "size":50,
   "_source":"Title",
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            //other clausule
         ]
      }
   },
   "knn":{
     "field": "FIELD_VECTOR",
     "query_vector": "YOUR_VECTOR",
     "k": 10,
     "num_candidates": 100
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated the source code as you suggested, 


`query ={
   "size":50,
   "_source":"Title",
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            # other clausule
         ]
      }
   },
   "knn":{
      "vectors":{
         "vector":"token_vector",
         "k":20
      }
   }
}


res = es.search(index='posting', body=query)`

I have got the following error message:

**BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'x_content_parse_exception', '[1:9] [knn] unknown field [vectors]')**


FYI, I am running elasticsearch locally on my laptop.

Comment: Thank you for reply. What is "FIELD_VECTOR" and "YOUR_VECTOR" in your example? Request you to please provide the answer. Thank You.

Comment: "FIELD_VECTOR" = The name of the vector field to search against. Must be a dense_vector field with indexing enabled.
"YOUR_VECTOR" = Query vector. Must have the same number of dimensions as the vector field you are searching against.
Read about [knn here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-knn).